# Locating the data directory for postgresql on mac

Tags: postgresql, csv, remote-server

If I run the following command in a postgresql that I connect to remotely:

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

it tells me

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data
```

If I copy a table from this remotely connected psql to a file and try to save it on my computer I would run this:

```
\copy table to 'fileFromTable.csv' csv;
```

Where did this file download to on my local machine? I cannot find it.

This location  /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data doesnt exist because I am assuming that location is from the remote location and not on my local system.  If I run SHOW data_directory from my local install of psql I get:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres
```

If I change directory to this location on my local machine (mac) there is no file or data folder in this directory.

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` command and creates the file on the *client* where `psql` is running. It seems you confused this with `copy` which is a SQL statement that is executed on the server and stores the file on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not specify an absolute path, I believe that by default the location of the CSV into which you copied the table should be the same as the path which was the active working directory when `psql` was started.  To mitigate this kind of ambiguity, you could always specify an absolute (local) path, for instance:

```
\copy my_table to '/path/to/my/file.csv' with csv;
```

You are correct about the data directory - that should be the location on the remote file system hosting the database service that contains the concrete files that back the database.